# Update all Rows and then send response sequelize

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I'm Pretty new doing this kind of tasks in Node. I have a POST method (express) which receives an array of objects like:

```
[{F1:'123',F2:'a',F3:'b',F4:'Z'},
{F1:'124',F2:'a',F3:'b',F4:'Z'},
{F1:'125',F2:'a',F3:'b',F4:'Z'},
{F1:'126',F2:'a',F3:'b',F4:'Z'},]
```

Then, I need do an Update for every object in the array.
I'm using sequelize:

```
MODEL.update(
    {
        att4: art['F4'],
    },
    {
    where:{
            att1: {$eq: art['F1']}
          }
    }).then(function(result)
    {        
        res.status(200).send();

    }).catch(function(err)
    {
        res.status(500).send(err);
    })
```

And this work for 1 object.

But I need the following: WHEN ALL THE UPDATES are processed, then send a response.

I tried with

```
req.body.forEach(function(o)
    {
        updateO(o)
    },this);
```

and in updateO(o) do the Model.Update, but I don't achieve the needed result.

Sorry for the bad English, I hope you can understand me and thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read about promises, all Sequelize's functions return promises, you can handle multiple querying through Promise.all

```
var objects = req.body;
Promise.all(objects.map(object=>{
    return MODEL.update({att4: object.F4},{where:{att1: object.F1});
})).then(function(result){        
    res.status(200).send();
}).catch(function(err){
    res.status(500).send(err);
})
```

Comment: Thank's. Reading some articles i get a similar aproach that work very similar to your answer!